# Altair: multiple y-axes on same chart

Tags: python, plot, altair, yaxis

I want to know how to make a plot like this (a plot having multiple y-axes), but in altair:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Start with a layered plot:

```py
base = alt.Chart(df).encode(
    x='time'
)
line = base.mark_line().encode(
    y='exp'
)
circle =  base.mark_circle().encode(
    y='sin'
)
```

Then when you 'call' the chart with `(line + circle)`, you add `.resolve_scale(y='independent')`

```py
(line + circle).resolve_scale(
    y = 'independent'
)
```